# Parsing JSON's from a server using React and Express - "TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express

I am having issues parsing a JSON returned from my server, in my client code. If I send a basic request to my mongoDB server:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/food/
```

I get the [following response,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGDVz.png) which is obviously an array of objects.

In my client, I have a state defined in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
 index: 0,
 foodList: []
};
```

And a function, callServer, which is called when the page is loaded using `componentWillMount()`:

```
callServer() {
 fetch("http://localhost:4000/food/")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => this.setState({ foodList: res }))
  .catch(err => err); 
}
```

This function populates the foodList in the files state with the server output - when I run `console.log("debug:\n" + JSON.stringify(this.statefoodList[0]))` the output is

```
Debug:
{"registerDate":"2020-04-01T14:34:04.834Z","_id":"5e66437d59a13ac97c95e9b9","image":"IMAGE","name":"Example 2","address":"BI1 111","type":"ExampleType1","price":"£Example Price","link":"example.com"}
```

Which shows that foodList is correctly set to be the output from the server.

The issue is, if I perform `console.log("debug:\n" + JSON.stringify(this.state.foodList[0].name))` I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**.

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now - I do not understand why the client believes foodList to be undefined when you can see from prior testing that it is not undefined, and it is in a JSON format.

As a side note, if it is important, I call `console.log()` from inside the `render()` method, but before the `return()` value.

I'm very new to the React framework and JS as a whole, so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You forgot a dot : `this.state.foodList[0].name)`

Comment: This was just a typo in this post, I will correct it, thankyou @BENARDPatrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a good thing to note in react is that the state changes happen asynchronously. Another good thing to note is that chrome likes to be helpful with console logs and will show what the values evaluate to currently rather than at the time. 
The main issue here (based on what you have written since we don't have code to look at) is that if the console log you have is run before the data call returns, then there won't be any data in the `foodList` array, so `this.state.foodList[0] ===undefined` and you can't access a property of undefined.
In react, if you want to console log a state change, a good option is to use the setState method's 2nd callback parameter. That is guaranteed to run after the state change.

```
callServer() {
 fetch("http://localhost:4000/food/")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => this.setState({ foodList: res },()=>console.log(this.state.foodList[0].name))
  .catch(err => err); 
}
```

If you want to keep the console.log in the render function, you can either check to make sure that the array is actually populated or use the new optional chaining operator (which is supported in the latest create react app versions):

```
console.log("debug:\n" + JSON.stringify(this.statefoodList[0]?.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to `console.log` the first element of the array before the array is populated with the data from your server (as the ajax call takes some tome to execute), so position 0 of this.state.foodList is still undefined.

You can fix this by first checking if the array has a length like this

```
console.log(this.state.foodList.length && "debug:\n" + JSON.stringify(this.state.foodList[0].name))
```

Comment: This solution worked! :) another user provided a slightly more "elegant" solution but thankyou very much for taking the time to help, it's useful information to know.

Comment: @ L. Warren Sure, just keep in mind that the solution offered by @Zachary Haber would work if you just want to `console .log` the response after fetching it, however if you would want to actually use the same data (`this.state.foodList[0].name`) within the render method to display the data, you would have to use something like what I mentioned above to check if it is defined before using it.

Comment: I'll bear it in mind, if I do come around to using your solution ultimately I'll be sure to mark yours as the correct answer :)